# The dart code in my project is notcolor coded

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I had the error that i was unable to create new project of flutter so i tried to reinstall flutter and dart then when i opened my old project i see

First The Code has no color except for brackets:
[image: Image 1(code no color)]

Second no dart/flutter logo before file name:
[image: no logo near file name (Image 2)]

I tried restarting, reinstalling extention but nothing changed

Any Help Would Be Appreciated.

Comment: Have you added the flutter path in the environment variables?

Comment: Yes I have added flutter path

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the issue just invalidate cache and restart your android studio

Comment: i am working on vs code